# couldn't save @ManyToOne child entities

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to save data using **JpaRepository** by providing the data of the child entity along with the data of parent entity but the save operation executes only for the parent entity but not for the child entities. Below is my implementation:

My Child entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "justchild", schema = "test")
public class JustChildEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8495817802073010928L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "cname", nullable = true)
    private String cname;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private JustParentEntity justParentEntity;

    // getters and setters
}
```

My parent entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "justparent", schema = "test")
public class JustParentEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -748956247024967638L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = true)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "justParentEntity", targetEntity = JustChildEntity.class)
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
    private Set<JustChildEntity> justChildEntities;

    // getters and setters
}
```

My implementation via the controller:

```java
@Autowired
private JustParentRepo justParentRepo;

@GetMapping("/test-persist-many")
@ResponseBody
public void testPersistMany() {

    JustParentEntity justParentEntity = new JustParentEntity();
    justParentEntity.setName("parent 1");

    JustChildEntity justChildEntity = new JustChildEntity();
    justChildEntity.setCname("child Name 1");
    justChildEntity.setJustParentEntity(justParentEntity);

    JustChildEntity justChildEntity2 = new JustChildEntity();
    justChildEntity2.setCname("child Name 2");
    justChildEntity.setJustParentEntity(justParentEntity);

    Set<JustChildEntity> justChildEntities = new HashSet<>();
    justChildEntities.add(justChildEntity);
    justChildEntities.add(justChildEntity2);

    justParentEntity.setJustChildEntities(justChildEntities);

    justParentRepo.save(justParentEntity);

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(justParentEntity);
        System.out.println(json);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My Repository interface:

```java
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface JustParentRepo extends JpaRepository<JustParentEntity, Long> {
}
```

My Seriallized json output is as follows:

```json
{
    "id": 8,
    "name": "parent 1",
    "justChildEntities": [{
        "id": 0,
        "cname": "child Name 1",
        "justParentEntity": null
    }, {
        "id": 0,
        "cname": "child Name 2",
        "justParentEntity": null
    }]
}
```

Here i see the child entities having no id value and neither foreign keys assigned. I am using Spring Boot 1.5.13. Please help.

**UPDATE**

i added `justParentRepo.flush()` after save but its not working.

My application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=12345
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=20000
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=50
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=20
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=15
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=3600000
spring.datasource.tomcat.validation-query=SELECT 1
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Comment: There is no cascade specified on the association, so nothing cascades. You also forgot to set the parent association to a non-null value... so it's null.

Comment: @JBNizet i tried your suggestion but its not working

Comment: You didn't set justChildEntity2.justParentEntity to justParentEntity before saving the parent (read your code **carefully**). And you're using the Hibernate proprietary Cascade annotation with a Hibernate proprietary SAVE_UPDATE value, that is not the right one. Use the standard cascade attribute, with PERSIST or ALL as a value.

Comment: thanks a lot @JBNizet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "justParentEntity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

If this does not work, could you specify your connection settings in your applications properties file ?

Comment: cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST or ALL is saving the child data but the forign key is saved only in one of the two child

Comment: Could you copy and paste your application.properties file settings as well as the error stack you get -if any- so we can better diagnose the issue ?

Comment: i am not getting any error. its just the foreign key is set null.